# "component" meaning in regards to Java technology?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I have come across the term "component" in various Java technology stack; some of the slang: "component based", "distributed components" , "EJB is component based" and so on..

I am confused on what does the term "component mean"; does it means the same thing in above slang or it changes with respect to context?

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: It's not slang, it's argot.

Answer (score 1):

A component is a self-contained unit of functionality with few or no dependencies on other parts of the program.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering#Definition_and_characteristics_of_components
defines it slightly differently.

It's a standard term in software engineering​, widely used and very easy to look up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so in simple words can it be thought of to be like "a piece of functionality"?

Comment: That's a good start. The idea of a component is that it has a well-defined wall around it. A statement is a piece of functionality but it can't stand independently at all. A component is an association of related pieces with a reasonably large purpose, requiring only sharply limited communication with its container or invoking piece, and otherwise standalone.

Comment: I urge you to look up the term as it relates to software, from multiple authoritative sources​. Don't try to learn computer programming on SO.